# Force an application to run on all users logged in to system

Tags: c#, psexec

I have two c# applications. One that I have that deploys to a computer, this is called AgentMgr, another one is called Agent. I then talk remotely to the AgentMgr to say what the configuration is, then it writes the configuration needed for the Agent to later use. Then I want (with out a computer restart) the Agent to run on all users that are currently logged in to the system under their non-elevated context, it will then allow them to perform specific hot keys, and what ever else the Agent needs to do, such as take a grab of their screen when needed by IT.

My question is, I would like to understand how to launch an application on behalf of all users logged into a machine, and under their context.

Comment: SignalR can be your friend in this.

Comment: What do you mean SignalR?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/804770/Implementing-SignalR-in-Desktop-Applications this might help you out, You can actually send pings to all the users you desire who are logged into the applications and make it run other stuff's as you wanted